# gettig deprecation warning for after create call back in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm getting a warning like below when I run RSpec tests

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of
>   after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new
>   return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after
>   `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To
>   maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute?`
>   instead. (called from set_about_page_title at (pry):12)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  after_create :create_defaults

  def create_defaults
    set_about_page_title
    set_contact_page_title
    self.save
  end

  def set_about_page_title
    self.about_page_title = self.full_name
  end

  def set_contact_page_title
    self.contact_page_title = User::GET_IN_TOUCH
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning says, `attribute_changed?` is deprecated and the new name is `saved_change_to_attribute`?

There are lot many methods that are deprecated and you can find them here https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25337#issuecomment-225166796